# pyparsing error

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I am stuck at this error in pyparsing

```
from pyparsing import Word,alphas,nums,Or,Regex,StringEnd
ws = Regex('\s*')
dot = "."
w = Word(alphas) + (ws | dot) + StringEnd()
w.leaveWhitespace()
w.parseString('AMIT.')
```

Returns the following error:

```
ParseException: Expected end of text (at char 4), (line:1, col:5)
```

Comment: ParseException: Expected end of text (at char 4), (line:1, col:5)

Comment: No Nick, StringEnd is defined. I forgot to write it here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`|` creates a "match first" expression, not "match longest".

The first alternative is the regex, which will match 0 or more whitespace characters. This, in fact, *does* match, so the dot is not parsed.

Then the next element to parse is `StringEnd`, but the parse position is still located at the '.'—so, fail!

Here is some more detailed output by adding `setDebug()` calls to your grammar expressions:

```
>>> w = Word(alphas).setDebug() + (ws.setDebug() | dot.setDebug()) + StringEnd()
>>> w.parseString('AMIT.')
Match W:(abcd...) at loc 0(1,1)
Matched W:(abcd...) -> ['AMIT']
Match Re:('\\s*') at loc 4(1,5)
Matched Re:('\\s*') -> ['']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\pyparsing-1.5.6-py2.6.egg\pyparsing.py", line 1032, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of text (at char 4), (line:1, col:5)
```

To get your grammar to work you could:

- change the `|` operator to `^` (match longest instead of match first)
- change the regex to `\s+` instead of `\s*` (so that at least one space was required for a match)
- change your second term to `Optional(dot)`

In general, explicit testing for whitespace is not consistent with the pyparsing philosophy—pyparsing is not the same as re.